# Drop-down with carousel

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, overflow, carousel

So I wrote a carousel in jQuery, but I want to have drop-down menus within the carousel. The problem is I'm using a container to hold the carousel with overflow set to hidden. This prevents the dropdowns from showing. Any ideas?

Here's [a link](http://www.fox.temple.edu/carousel/) where you can see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I fixed it by wrapping the container that had the overflow:hidden in another div that had a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow:hidden cannot be overriden. 
You could try to wrap the buttons in a parent with overflow:hidden and the sub-lists outside but then aligning the button with it's sub-menu will become the problem. Javascript can help in that case.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but the drop downs would disappear when you un-hovered the li because they aren't inside the li anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `overflow:hidden`, you should use the new "micro clearfix".

Go here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

In your markup, simply just add the class "cf" on your container